# How to add My App as option in the selection text toolbar in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want as soon as I select the text in any App of the mobile, it shows me an additional option to my App
How can i apply that?

Thanks in advance to any help

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[flutter_process_text: ^1.1.2](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_process_text)

> Why use Flutter Process Text? # Flutter Process Text Plugin is known
> for :
>
> Flutter Process Text  Flutter Process Text Fast, performant &
> compatible    Free & Open-source Production ready Make App Reactive

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/lavahasif/fdservers .please check this code. it may helpful.you need much work in android side.i use this plugin and my custom code. share file and test to flutter app from toolbar

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this plugin didn't navigate to my App what if I want to navigate to my App immediately after choosing this additional option of the selection toolbar
Will I have to edit in the native code (Java or Kotlin) and also Swift

Comment: yes you need to chage in android and ios side that mentioned in document

Comment: https://github.com/lavahasif/fdservers/blob/master/fdserver.apk

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code helped me a lots